# How the electric charge of 1 electron is distributed over its volume?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, matter

Can we say the electric charge density of an electron is distributed uniformly over its spherical volume?

Answer (score 6):

No we can't, because as near as we can tell the electron occupies zero volume. All experiments thus far indicate that to the limit of our testing capabilities, the electron is a point object with zero radius.

Comment: Then how they assign the radius to the electron? Also the mass?

Comment: In your title you say the electron is infinitesimal.

Comment: Your second sentence is correct, but it contradicts the first sentence.  We cannot conclude that the electron has zero volume given the limit of our testing capabilites.

Comment: will edit my answer. -NN

Comment: I meant small not zero as inferred from infinitesimal. I edited my title.

Comment: Aria, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius, where indeed sometimes one assigns a "radius" to the electron which when treated as a classical (non quantum-mechanical) ball of charge, would yield the same total energy that the electron should have according to special relativity ($E=mc^2$). But this isn't a real radius, and the electron is usually treated in quantum mechanics as a point particle, not a ball with a radius.

Answer (score 2):

In quantum mechanics the charge density is given by $\rho=q|\psi|^2$. This is not generally uniformly distributed, and it is also very often not spherical either.

Note that this concept of charge density is not exactly the same as the charge density that you are used to in classical mechanics (similarly the concept of quantum spin is not the same as the classical concept of spin). So be careful about over-interpreting the above equation as some definite solid charge density.

Comment: The classic radius of electron is it found from the average of q sai^2?

Comment: No, the classical electron radius has nothing to do with $\psi$. It is just a bunch of fundamental constants related to electrons with the overall dimensions of length. It is not very meaningful, in my opinion.

Comment: Since the charge density of electron is $q |\psi|^2$, since $|\psi|$ is not uniform so $\rho$ won't be uniform too, am I right?

Comment: The volume described by the wave function should not be identified with the particle volume.

Comment: @my2cts agreed, but the charge density of the particle is nonetheless given by $\rho|\psi|^2$. If the OP had asked about the particle volume I would have responded as Niels did, but the question of the charge density is a different question than the volume and has a different answer. This answer is important e.g. for applying Maxwell’s equations.

Comment: @Dale The probability distribution of a charged point (electron) or near-point (ptoton) particle, should not be identified with the charge distribution of that particle.

Comment: @my2cts this is standard terminology to identify $q|\psi|^2$ as charge density https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_density#Charge_density_in_quantum_mechanics  In non-relativistic quantum electrodynamics Heisenberg equations on the EM field is Maxwell's equations, and $q|\psi|^2$ is $\rho$. So in a very legitimate sense it is correct to call it the charge density. This is not poor terminology. Quantum charge density is not the same as a classical charge density, just as quantum spin is not the same as classical spin. But it is legitimate and standard terminology to use the same words for each

Comment: @Dale, this is a good answer but the person who asked the original question, as it was phrased, might not understand its context. Basically, your answer refers not to a free electron but an electron inside some system (e.g., an atom) which exists not at a single point and not at a sphere but probabilistically distributed over some non-spherical "orbital". I think the original question was really about a free particle - and what it looks like. We usually consider the free electron as being a single point, not a sphere. But see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius.